# Within a UITableView cell, how can I lazy-load images which fade in?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

How can I lazy load images in a UITableView cell, with a fade-in effect when the image is loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reffering to Asynchronous images. There is a great article available at: http://www.markj.net/iphone-asynchronous-table-image/

Within the connectionDidFInishLoading just put the later after this

```
UIImageView* imageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data]] autorelease];
//Paste below code here
```

to fade it in:

```
//Paste following here
imageView.alpha = 0.0f;
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5f];

imageView.alpha = 1.0f;

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: Thanks but I need a fade in effect.

Answer (score 5):

[**SDImageWeb**](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) is a pretty good library which does what you need. It even has image cache, so once the images are downloaded, then next time they are picked from local flash memory.

What this does not do is `fadeIn` effect. But this is pretty easy to add, with `UIView` animations.

So to asynchronously download an image, 
 `[imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]];`

thats all..

To Put in fadein animation.

```
- (void)fadeInLayer:(CALayer *)l
{
    CABasicAnimation *fadeInAnimate   = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    fadeInAnimate.duration            = 0.5;
    fadeInAnimate.repeatCount         = 1;
    fadeInAnimate.autoreverses        = NO;
    fadeInAnimate.fromValue           = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
    fadeInAnimate.toValue             = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
    fadeInAnimate.removedOnCompletion = YES;
    [l addAnimation:fadeInAnimate forKey:@"animateOpacity"];
    return;
}
```

To call this - `[self fadeInLayer: imageView.layer];`

This should do the trick. This animates, your image from alpha 0 to 1 in 0.5 seconds ! To give the wonderful fade in animation.

Comment: Thank you dude. Can you say me how to add the fadeIn effect programmatically? When the user scroll and see other UIImageViews I would a fadeIn effect for appear the images.